# Jquery append function with toggle event

Tags: jquery, css

While call toggle function through the column button i will apply hide style for column in parent div by uncheck the column name.
If i call keyup function through textbox mean the append function load the data without the hide style.
Please help how to apply hide style after load the data for parent div.

[**Here is fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tamizh/TUNAP/20/)

```
 $(this).is(":checked") ? $("#tbl_tasks .tbcol"+id).css("display","table-cell") : $("#tbl_tasks .tbcol"+id).css("display","none");
```

Here i hide the column but data not hide after call table load function.

Comment: your question is totally messy can you edit it and rephrase it in simple words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your table load function...

```
$( ".view_column_list input[type=checkbox]" ).each( function( e ) {
    var id = $( this ).val();
    $( this ).is( ":checked" ) ? $( "#tbl_tasks .tbcol" + id ).css( "display", "table-cell" ) : $( "#tbl_tasks .tbcol" + id ).css( "display", "none" );
} )
```

It just re-uses your hiding logic, but is not called on change event, instead loops through selected checkboxes.

Fiddle updated here: http://jsfiddle.net/TUNAP/21/